# Windows Phone 7 UserExtendedProperties

Tags: windows-phone-7

After being directed here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.info.userextendedproperties.getvalue%28v=VS.92%29.aspx

I tried the following code on my sideloaded application.  All that was written out was the **000001** value.

*I knew that would be the case in the emulator*, but I was hoping to get a real value when it was on my phone.  Any ideas?

```
                 int ANIDLength = 32;  
                 int ANIDOffset = 2;

                 string result = string.Empty;  
                 object anid;  
                 if (UserExtendedProperties.TryGetValue("ANID", out anid))  
                 {
                     if (anid != null && anid.ToString().Length >= (ANIDLength + ANIDOffset))
                     {
                         result = anid.ToString().Substring(ANIDOffset, ANIDLength);
                     }
                     else
                     {
                         result = "000001";
                     } 
                 }
```

Comment: are you printing the value of `result`?

Comment: I'm actually sending the value of result to a webservice that inserts a record into my table.

Comment: Jeff, please see [Asking why someone deleted their own question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73147/asking-why-someone-deleted-their-own-question). Thanks!

Comment: @Arjan - Please see my comment below.  I deleted it because there was a bug in my code.  Technically the way I was doing it was correct, however, I misplaced my result variable which over-wrote the anid.  So I didn't want it to be a distraction for someone that was looking for a solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to remove 1 from the calculation of your length check to account for the substring operation working on a zero based index:

```
 if (anid != null && anid.ToString().Length >= (ANIDLength + ANIDOffset - 1))
```

This works on my machine:

```
private string GetAnid()
{
    object anidValue;

    int ANIDLength = 32;
    int ANIDOffset = 2;

    if (UserExtendedProperties.TryGetValue("ANID", out anidValue))
    {
        if (anidValue != null && anidValue.ToString().Length >= (ANIDLength + ANIDOffset - 1))
        {
            return anidValue.ToString().Substring(ANIDOffset, ANIDLength);
        }
        else
        {
            return "???";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return "???";
    }
}
```

Comment: I just tried that and redeployed to my phone and it did not work.  I still get 000001.

Comment: @Jeff I voted to undelete, along with three other users. Deleting questions after a satisfactory answer has been received is not how SO is supposed to work.

Comment: @Pekka - I agree!  However, the reason why I deleted it was that it was a bug in MY code.  So the question really wasn't valid...  As my original code worked except that I put the results variable after the if so it always set it to 000001.  I didn't want it to be a distraction to someone actually needing to know how to do this...