# ANID and ANID2 Lengths aren't 32 as The API Said

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

After reading the documentation for [UserExtendedProperties.TryGetValue(string propertyName,
    out Object propertyValue)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.info.userextendedproperties.trygetvalue.aspx)

The documentation said:

> The string returned by the ANID and ANID2 properties contains the anonymous identifier and is 32 characters long.

But when i tested ANID2  on my device (WP8), the length of returned string was 44.

After doing some search I found this [article](http://thesociablegeek.com/windows-phone-7/wp7-getting-unique-device-and-user/) which Includes this method to extract ANID:

```
  private const int ANIDLength = 32;
  private const int ANIDOffset = 2;

  public static string GetWindowsLiveAnonymousID()
    {
        string result = string.Empty;
        object anid;
        if (UserExtendedProperties.TryGetValue("ANID", out anid))
        {
            if (anid != null && anid.ToString().Length >= (ANIDLength + ANIDOffset))
            {
                result = anid.ToString().Substring(ANIDOffset, ANIDLength);
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

My questions: Is this the correct method to extract ANID and ANID2? and why the returned string length wasn't 32 from the beginning as the API said?

The reason that I asked this question was a another [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4520387/windows-phone-7-userextendedproperties) related to this topic, And the answer was to subtract 1 from the check of the above method. Which one is correct and why?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**ANID2 is bounded to** the the **Windows Live Account Id**, and the **Publisher GUID**. So, applications from **different publisher will get different values of ANID2**.

This link dives into a bit more details-   [ANID2](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-us/7e265aed-1719-4158-bc98-5d985e694c4c/userextendedproperties-anid-anid2-changes-in-wp8?forum=wpdevelop)

extract :

**The following holds true for Windows Phone 8 too.**

The format in WP7 was like (I x-ed out a few chars): **`A=E32ACBXXXXXXXXX3B337B68CFFFFFFFF&E=d59&W=1`**

In WP7 it was necessary to parse the value after A= up to &E= as the other values could change over time.